# Random number in Java where one number has higher odds

Tags: java

I understand that in Java I can generate a random number with the following code:

```
Random rand=new Random() 
int x=rand.nextInt(1);
```

I am interested generating either the number `zero` or `one`. But I want that number `one` has 90% higher probability of of being generated than zero.

How can I achieve that?

thanks

EDIT:
Thanks everyone. It's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres a pretty compact way to express it

```
Random rand=new Random();
int x = ((rand.nextInt(10) == 0)) ? 0 : 1;
```

Answer (score 5):

Generate a random number from 0 to 9. If the number is 0, you return zero. If the number is 1-9, you return one.

Answer (score 2):

This would do it:

```
int result;
if (Math.random() < 0.9) {
    result = 1;
}
else {
    result = 0;
}
```

Or more concise:

```
int result = (Math.random() < 0.9) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: to cross yours with @SamG-H I think int result = ((rand.nextDouble() > 0.9)) ? 0 : 1;  would be best.

Comment: @SeanF Yeah, I thought of writing it that way, but decided that the if-else approach is preferable here because it allows the future possibility of having more than just two options. Since you suggested it, though, I've added the `?:` approach as well.

Answer (score 2):

read nextInt(int) manual which says:

Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence. The general contract of nextInt is that one int value in the specified range is pseudorandomly generated and returned. All n possible int values are produced with (approximately) equal probability. The method nextInt(int n) is implemented by class Random as if by:

change your code to
     `Random rand=new Random();
     int x=rand.nextInt(10); 
     return (x == 0) ? 0 : 1;`
 then run it again

Comment: yeah, i missed the point. Random rand=new Random() int x=rand.nextInt(10); return (x == 0) ? 0 : 1;

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this.

```
int x = (int) (Math.random() / 0.9); // 90% chance of 0
```

or

```
int x = (int) (Math.random() + 0.9); // 90% chance of 1
```